# How to check availability of each separated string in array?

Tags: php

I have a string with pipe symbol | where i need to check each piped value is contain in the $attrib array

so if the each value is present show success or show error.

**PHP**

```
<?php

  $fields  = "NAME|PHONE|EMAIL";
  $get_each_val = expolde('|',$fields)

  $attribs = array
     (   
        "NAME"     => "Jony", 
        "EMAIL"    => "jonyJoe@abc.com",
        "LOCATION" => "Xyz", 
        "ADDRESS"  => "23 Street",              
        "MESSAGE"  => "Hi there!" 
    );

   //need to check 

   if  $get_each_val  // exploded from $fields

   contain in

   array_keys($attribs)

   if 
       //$get_each_val is present in $attribs  

       echo $get_each_val.' - success<br/>';
   else
       echo  $get_each_val.' - error <br/>';

?>
```

**OUTPUT LIKE:**

```
      NAME  - success 

      PHONE - error

      EMAIL - success
```

Comment: your question is unclear after `array_keys($attribs)` . Please elaborate with your expected outcome

Comment: just  need to check each value separated with | from   $fields  = "NAME|PHONE|EMAIL";  and that each value is present in  $attribs aray or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inbuilt function array_key_exists() function to check if key exist or not.

```
<?php
  $fields  = "NAME|PHONE|EMAIL";
  $get_each_val = explode('|',$fields);

 $attribs = array (
   "NAME"=> "Jony",
   "EMAIL"=> "jonyJoe@abc.com",
   "LOCATION"=> "Xyz",
   "ADDRESS"=> "23 Street",
   "MESSAGE"=> "Hi there!"
 );
foreach ($get_each_val as $value) {
   if(array_key_exists($value, $attribs)){
      echo $value.'- success<br/>';
   }else{
      echo $value.'- error<br/>';
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
<?php
  $fields  = "NAME|PHONE|EMAIL";
   $get_each_val = explode('|',$fields);

  $attribs = array
 (
   "NAME"=> "Jony",
   "EMAIL"=> "jonyJoe@abc.com",
   "LOCATION"=> "Xyz",
   "ADDRESS"=> "23 Street",
   "MESSAGE"=> "Hi there!"
 );
    foreach ($get_each_val as $value) {

 if(isset($attribs[$value]))
 {
       echo $value.' - success<br/>';
  }
  else
  {
     echo  $value.' - error <br/>';
  }
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Remember that this won't work for null values inside $attribs array.